# how to install firebird client only in raspberry pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, firebird

I'm new to Raspberry Pi. I have an application that uses a firebird database and i want to run my application in raspberry pi. The database is located on another machine on which firebird server is installed.

So on raspberry pi, I need only the firebird client. Can any one give instructions to install client only on raspberry pi? Do I need to install anything for firebird access from my application in Raspberry Pi?

Comment: It depends on which linux you have installed on your raspberry. See http://mapopa.blogspot.nl/2012/11/debian-and-raspberry-pi-love-small-arm.html for an example with Debian. It describes a full server, but installing libfbclient2 should be sufficient.

Comment: i am using debian wheezy on raspberry pi

Answer (score 2):

You can use libfbclient2 from debian wheezy as Mark explained

http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/libfbclient2

```
apt-get install libfbclient2
```

Comment: operation failsedand getting following message "unable to fetch some archives ,may be run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?"

Comment: it's a [dns issue](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=17016) `sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf`

and then add the lines to the file:
`nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4`